# using filename and path as strings to be replaced using sed command

Tags: text-processing, sed, find, path

I am trying to deal with the following situation. I have many files (more than 100) with an `.html` extension in a folder tree and inside those files I have a string which is the file name. For example I have the following files:

`file1.html` located in `subfolder1/subfolderA/` which somewhere in the file contains the string `file1.html`.

`file2.html` located in `subfolder1/subfolderB/` which somewhere in the file contains the string `file2.html`

`file3.html` located in `subfolder2/subfolderC/` which somewhere in the file contains the string `file3.html`.

and so on.

Basically, I want to go through the entire tree structure, find the string which is identical to the file name and replace it with the path + file name, stripping the `.html`.

Therefore, in the example above, I want to replace:

- in file `file1.html`:

  replace `file1.html` with `subfolder1/subfolderA/file1`
- in `file2.html`:

  replace `file2.html` with `subfolder1/subfolderB/file2`
- in file3.html:

  replace `file3.html` with `subfolder2/subfolderC/file3`

I know how to replace strings using `find` and `sed`. I used the following command:

`find . -type f -name \*.html -exec sed -i.bak 's|<old string>|<new string>|g' {} +`

However, in that case "old string" and "new string" need to be hard coded.

How can I achieve the above with

"old string" = the filename + file extension

"new string" = the path + filename - file extension

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do what you specify with `find` and `exec` alone. Try piping `find`'s result into a small `while` loop:

```
find . -type f -name \*.html | while read PN; do sed "s|${PN##*/}|${PN%.*}|g" "$PN"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Tested and Worked fine

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter the input"
read p
cd $p
echo "enter the file"
read f
if [[ -f $p/$f ]]
then
echo "file exsists"

grep -io "$f" $p/$f >/dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]
then
r=`echo $f | sed "s/\.txt//g"`
echo $r
awk -v f="$f" -v r="$r" '{gsub(f,r,$0);print }' $f 
fi
fi
```